# Mistakenly selected remove from sidebar xml preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-settings

I am using Android Studio 2.2 preview, and I have mistakenly choose Layout preview settings to remove from sidebar which appears in the  left side. Now how do i get back? Its missing from sidebar. Only i can see is gradle.

Comment: all toolbar is removed or only layout preview..

Comment: No, You are not getting what i mean. In Android Studio at the left sidebar you can see Preview  and Gradle by default right? When you click Preview you will see a mobile but  above  there's a settings which i selected was  "removed from sidebar" and now there is no Preview tool in Sidebar i want to get it back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to view -> windowtools and you can see option their like below image

[image: like this]

Comment: Yes thank you very much amit but its comming in window not like before in the side.. When i click on Preview a  new window will popup. I want it like before.  How to solve that? I just played few settings but it's not sitting.
Lost
No Pinned Mode and 
Dock Option

Comment: open your preview in pop and their is setting icon on top.. what you want you select their see edited answer